# I cannot find the FF Multi Converter for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, files, conversion

Is there a version of FF Multi Converter for Ubuntu 14.04? I installed the PPA, but the program exists only for older versions. In PPA there is not a version for Ubuntu Trusty. Is there a place where I could get it?

Answer (score 2):

I install ffmulticonverter 1.6 Stable from PPA on UbuntuStudio 14.04 x386 and have no problems, working fine.

You need:

1. Install ffmpeg for Ubuntu 14.04 from this PPA with:

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media`

   `sudo apt-get update`

   `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`

next you need remove this respository to avoid problems with some updates of other packages:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
```

Then update:

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

2.- Install FFmulticonverter 1.6 from Stable PPA with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ffmulticonverter/stable    

sudo apt-get update    

sudo apt-get install ffmulticonverter
```

Working fine on UbuntuStudio 14.04, Now you have the best Video Converter Software of all times for Linux.

Next is you want convert some image files to other install:

`sudo apt-get install python-pythonmagick`

And if you want convert Libreoffice files to Microsoft Office files install:

`sudo apt-get install unoconv`

But take care, this metod only working if only use the libreoffice that come with the default Ubuntu packages, because if you install the deb file that you can download from www.libreoffice.org you can't install correctly unoconv

Answer (score 0):

Presumably because of the deprecation of ffmpeg (which FF multiconverter needs) we at present do not have  a stable release available.

However if you are not scared of bugs you may try out the unstable release, which is available for 14.04 from the [unstable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ffmulticonverter/+archive/unstable):

```
ppa:ffmulticonverter/unstable
```

Also see: [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Answer (score 0):

Now are other way, but **danger**, if you use kdenlive not try this metod:

FFMultiConverter is now available for Ubuntu 14.04 & Linux Mint 17
http://www.noobslab.com/2014/08/ffmulticonverter-is-now-available-for.html

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jon-severinsson/ffmpeg
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ffmulticonverter/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmulticonverter ffmpeg
```

Working on UbuntuStudio 14.04.1, but this package of ffmpeg updates (without you permission) other packages that depend of kdenlive (like libavcodec-54-extra, etc), this new packages delete the video profiles (codecs) that come by default on kdenlive: "HDV, Raw DV, AVI DV, MPEG-2, MPEG-4, XVid4, H.264, Flash, RealVideo, Theora, WebM". For this reason I have to format my laptop to a fresh installation of UbuntuStudio 14.04.1 (there is no way to repair the damage). For this reason I suggest the first way show above.